# Node_color not matching with nodelist in networkx graph

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx

I am making graphs with networkx. My nodes are book titles, each of which has an attribute for the race of the author. I am coloring the nodes according to race, with the following code:

```
node_color = []

for node in C.nodes(data=True):
    try:
        if node[1]['RACE'] == 0.0:
            node_color.append('blue')
        elif node[1]['RACE'] == 1.0:
            node_color.append('red')
        elif node[1]['RACE'] == 2.0:
            node_color.append('green')
    except(TypeError, KeyError):
        node_color.append('brown')
```

The dictionary of the nodes and attributes is working correctly (writers are correctly matched with race), but the nodes are incorrectly colored in the end (Toni Morrison's The Bluest Eye is colored blue, ie, instead of red). Here is my drawing code:

```
print (nx.draw_random(C, node_color=node_color, 
labels=labelDict,node_size=[v * 300 for v in eigDict.values()], width = 
.02, font_size=9))
```

I'm not sure why node_color=node_color is not correctly mapping. My only thought is that I also create a dictionary of eigenvector centrality for the size of the nodes. Maybe this changes the order of the nodelist when I graph C?

```
import operator
eigDict = nx.eigenvector_centrality(C)
sorted_eigDict = sorted(eigDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), 
reverse=True)
```

How can I get the nodes correctly colored?

Comment: ok. I discovered that len(node_color) and len(C.nodes()) are different. that's the problem. but i don't know *why* they are different.

Comment: can you write a minimal example of your error? for instance including how you make your graph `C`?

Comment: See [mcve] for help asking this question.